# Align divs next to each other CSS (Cards Style)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to align cards that are wrapped up in divs. What I want to do is align those cards beside each other until it reaches maximum screen width, then I want it to move to the next line automatically.

The problem is that once I copy the html code, the new copied card spawns on top of the previous card rather than next to each other.

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="fighter-card">

        <div class="front active">
            <div class="ranking-position">1</div>

            <div class="more">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="fighter-picture">
                <img src="~/images/Resources/RankingsPhotos/Lomachenko.png" />
            </div>

            <ul class="information">
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Name:</div>
                    <div class="information-right">aa</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Weight:</div>
                    <div class="information-right">aa</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Belts:</div>
                    <div class="information-right">aa</div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="back">

            <div class="go-back">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

            <ul class="information">
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Yesterday</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Today</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">None of your business</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Yesterday</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">Today</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="information-left">aa</div>
                    <div class="information-right">9<sup>o</sup></div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

<div class="fighter-card">
//Next div with the same content for testing
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .fighter-card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    }

    .fighter-card .front {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #171717;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .5s;
    transform-origin: right;
    float: left;
}

.ranking-position {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.more {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.fighter-picture {
    background-size: cover;
}

.information {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.information li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}

.information li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.information li .information-left {
    width: 50%;
}

.information li .information-right {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}

.fighter-card .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: .5s;
    transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(90deg);
}

.fighter-card .back.active {
    transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0deg);
}

.fighter-card .front.active {
    transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0deg);
}

.fighter-card .front {
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg);
}

.go-back {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
}

.go-back .fa {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.more').click(function () {
        $('.back').addClass('active')
        $('.front').removeClass('active')
    });

    $('.go-back').click(function () {
        $('.back').removeClass('active')
        $('.front').addClass('active')
    });
});
```

I know it's a lot of code here entered. Just want to make sure that everything that could be related to this problem is included.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use absolute positioning and specify the location, then you should do that for each card. If not, let the browser do the positioning by using `display: inline-block` or `float: left` (if there is other content on the line).

Comment: I used positioning : absolute...it's not doing anything. It just put the div on top of another div. Whenever I use display: inline-block or float: left on fighter-card it puts the card at the very top left of the corner rather than in the center like it originally was.

Comment: You need to create a parent div and use the `position: absolute` on it. Don't put `position:absolute` on **.fighter-card**.